# Given that $a+b = c+d = 10$ and $|a-b| > |c-d|$, show that $ab<cd$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

By substitution

$$ab<cd \iff a(10-a) < c (10-c) $$
$$|a-b|>|c-d| \iff |a-5|>|c-5|$$

By graphing $y(x)=x(10-x)$, this equation is a quadratic that has a turning point at $(x,y)=(5,25)$ and it open downwards. So the closer $x$ is from $5$, the greater the $y$ value. The second inequality is saying $a$ is further away from $5$ than $c$ is so $y(a) < y(c)$.

I am struggling to show this just by using algebraic manipulation. How can this be shown more rigorously?

Comment: Looks like $a+b = c+d = 10$ can be replaced with just $a+b = c+d$. Is there a special name for this inequality?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for (hence I'm putting it in the comments), but geometrically the rectangle with side lengths $a,b$ is less "square-like" than the rectangle with side lengths $c,d$. Knowing that the area of a rectangle given the perimeter (i.e. 20 in this case) is maximized when it's a square, the inequality is true. Not a rigorous proof, but I thought it's a fun perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint*:
$$|a-b|\ge |c-d|$$ $$\to |a-b|^2\ge |c-d|^2$$ $$\to {(a+b)}^2-4ab\ge {(c+d)}^2-4cd$$ Can you end it now?

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach

$a,b = 5+r, ~5-r$ in some order.

$c,d = 5+s, ~5-s$ in some order.

Since $|a-b| > |c-d|,$ you have that $r > s.$

**Edit**
See comments following answer.  Above should be
$|r| > |s|$, or I should have specified that $r,s$ were positive.

Therefore $(ab) = 5^2 - r^2 < 5^2 - s^2 = (cd)$.

Comment: Good trick! Upvoted. Should there be |r|>|s| though?

Comment: @BrightStar good point.  I was assuming that (for example) $a,b$ and then $c,d$ were expressible where $r,s$ were both positive numbers.  I should have specified that in my answer.